# Multiple user authentication in zookeeper with sasl from single java application

Tags: java, apache-zookeeper, apache-curator

I have zookeeper configuration that allows clients to authenticate via sasl (with digest md5). Zookeeper is configured to use sasl, sasl auth provider is present in zookeeper configuration. I have jaas config with list of all users. Each of client has it's own jaas config file with user and password. In this configuration everything works fine - clients are able to use zookeeper.

But here is the thing. I have some clients that can't connect to zookeeper directly - it connects and authenticate into separate module. This module (written in Java) understands incoming requests and use Curator Framework client to communication with zookeeper, and then returns result if needed.

Java module has it's own jaas config for authentication (user/password), so basically it can authenticate inside zookeeper as a one user - even that there is many users (with separate user/pass) that authenticate in this module.

How can I achieve that java module can authenticate in zookeeper as many users (if user1 calls java module, it should authenticate as user1 in zookeeper, if user2 calls java module, it should authenticate a user2, etc.)

Here is one of approach that i've tried (I am aware that this approach is not the best one, but I'm not zookeeper's expert, so I had no better idea yet):

- Java module has many jaas configs (one for each user).
- When requests arrives and user authenticate itself in java module - module selects jaas config (by setting system property java.security.auth.login.config to point to one of jaas configs)
- Module creates new Curator Framework client (it will be cached for latter requests from the same user)
- Module uses new client to perform operation on zookeeper

It was surprise for me that sasl authentication was performed only once - for first curator client. All other clients "share" the same authentication.

Is there any way that each client will use separate authentication to zookeeper?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understood the problem correctly, but it might be related to the fact that apache ZK client internally creates the Login object as a singleton, which means every client within the same JVM will get the first/same auth login credentials.

Comment: Yes, you are right - I've found this singleton Login object during debuging of curator client. So it probably mean that I can't log in with many users from single JVM. Probably I need to find another solution. Maybe do you have some ideas?

Comment: I tried manually patching the client code and removing the singleton logic (maybe just remove the static modifier), and the testing showed the singleton there is not really necessary. It seems to be just a precaution. However, I wouldn't trust this works just like this, it would need to be verified. Other options are to have different JVM's per connection (e.g. using curator proxy recipe), which I assume is also not a nice approach. 

I'm not sure if this is a bug in ZK client code, because there seems to be no mention of this in Jira.

Comment: I'm thinking of something like that (my inspiration http://michaelmorello.blogspot.co.uk/2012/12/zookeeper-netflix-curator-and-acls.html): I will create one curator client per one user - but I will pass information about "real" user using custom auth info. Then, on zookeeper side, I will use custom authentication provider that will check passed data and call addAuthInfo on ServerCnxn (I probably need also to remove auth info about user that authenticated by SASL mechanism). If I'm not wrong - now many user can "use" zookeeper via my java module and with respect to each other ACLs.